# Traer registros con tiempo entre 3 y 24 horas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una tabla en `MySQL` con un campo de tipo `time`, en donde guardo tiempos que pueden ser menores o mayores a 24 horas, por ejemplo `'02:20:00'`, `'23:00:00'`,`'150:00:00'`. Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema radica en que quiero obtener todos los registros que estén entre `'03:00:00'` y `'24:00:00'`, con lo que tengo la siguiente condición en mi consulta:

```
select * from mi_tabla where tiempo_respuesta between '03:00:00' and '24:00:00'
```

Esta consulta me regresa los valores con un tiempo de '03:00:00', hasta los que tienen tiempo de `'249:00:00'`, lo cual no tiene sentido para mi. Incluso hice esta consulta solo a manera de prueba:

```
select cast('24:00:00' as time) > '249:00:00'
```

Dandome como resultado `TRUE`.

Si alguien me pudiera orientar se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: El problema es que no estás convirtiendo las cadenas a time, prueba así: `select * from mi_tabla where tiempo_respuesta between time('03:00:00') and time('24:00:00')`. Es por eso mismo que la comprobación te da true, si conviertes a `time` dará `false`: `select cast('24:00:00' as time) >time( '249:00:00')`

Comment: muchísimas gracias hermano, me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás convirtiendo las cadenas a `time`, prueba así:

```
 select * from mi_tabla where tiempo_respuesta between time('03:00:00') and time('24:00:00');
```

Es por eso mismo que la comprobación te da true, si conviertes a `time` dará false:

```
  select cast('24:00:00' as time) >time( '249:00:00')
```

Si no conviertes el valor de cadena a un objeto temporal no estás comparando entre iguales. El resultado puede ser cualquier cosa no conforme a lo que esperas.